# jquery idletimeout and store.js across multiple browser tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery [idletimeout](https://github.com/JillElaine/jquery-idleTimeout) and [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) plugin in my MVC 5 application.
I tried much but still couldn't run the example.
How to use the [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js)

i am presuming that Store.js seems to be made for Node.js ?
how can i use both plugin in MVC 5.

My tried code is written below:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/app/FrontEnd/js/json.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/app/FrontEnd/js/require.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/app/FrontEnd/js/store.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/app/FrontEnd/js/jquery-idleTimeout.min.js"></script>` $(document).ready(function () {      
        //var engine = require('../src/store-engine')
        //var store = localStorage;
        //if (store.se) {
        //    store.set('idleTimerLoggedOut', true);
        //} else {
        //    alert('Dependent file missing. Please see: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js');
        //} 

        $(document).idleTimeout({
            redirectUrl: '/logout',      // redirect to this url on logout. Set to "redirectUrl: false" to disable redirect

            // idle settings
            idleTimeLimit: 1200,           // 'No activity' time limit in seconds. 1200 = 20 Minutes
            idleCheckHeartbeat: 2,       // Frequency to check for idle timeouts in seconds

            // optional custom callback to perform before logout
            customCallback: false,       // set to false for no customCallback
            // customCallback:    function () {    // define optional custom js function
            // perform custom action before logout
            // },

            // configure which activity events to detect
            // http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events
            activityEvents: 'click keypress scroll wheel mousewheel mousemove', // separate each event with a space

            // warning dialog box configuration
            enableDialog: true,           // set to false for logout without warning dialog
            dialogDisplayLimit: 20,       // 20 seconds for testing. Time to display the warning dialog before logout (and optional callback) in seconds. 180 = 3 Minutes
            dialogTitle: 'Session Expiration Warning', // also displays on browser title bar
            dialogText: 'Because you have been inactive, your session is about to expire.',
            dialogTimeRemaining: 'Time remaining',
            dialogStayLoggedInButton: 'Stay Logged In',
            dialogLogOutNowButton: 'Log Out Now',

            // error message if https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js not enabled
            errorAlertMessage: 'Please disable "Private Mode", or upgrade to a modern browser. Or perhaps a dependent file missing. Please see: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js',

            // server-side session keep-alive timer
            sessionKeepAliveTimer: 600,   // ping the server at this interval in seconds. 600 = 10 Minutes. Set to false to disable pings
            sessionKeepAliveUrl: window.location.href // set URL to ping - does not apply if sessionKeepAliveTimer: false
        });
    });`
```

and i am receiving the following error message:

Please disable "Private Mode", or upgrade to a modern browser. Or perhaps a dependent file missing. Please see: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a dependency. Try to download jquery.min.js and jqueryui.min.js and add them to your class as an other script that you would like to attach.

Example:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/store.everything.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-idleTimeout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```